# How to implement following R function?

Tags: r, math, statistics, probability

I am trying to create a function to do the following in R:

> Input parameters `n` , `s` , `x-bar` all integers.
>
> 1. Generate `n - 1` random numbers using `rnorm( n - 1 , 0 , 1)`.
> 2. Take each of the numbers, square it, and add them up and store the sum into `x`. Divide integer `s` by `x` and take square root of the result and
>      store into `sigma`
> 3. Generate a single value from N(0,1). `rnorm( 1 , 0 , 1)` and store into `Z`.
> 4. Then store into `mu` the value of `Z x ( sigma / sqrt(n) ) + x-bar`.
> 5. Print out `mu`.

Any help would be appreciated !

My attempt( Is this right ?)

```
g <- function( n , s , xb ) { 
  vals <- rnorm( n - 1 , 0 , 1) 
  sum <- 0
  for( i in vals ) 
  { 
    sum <- sum + (i * i )
    print( sum )
  }

  sigma <- sqrt ( s / sum )
  z <- rnorm(1, 0 , 1)
  mu <- ( z * ( sigma / sqrt(n) ) + xb )
  print ( mu)
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Edited. Can you please check ?

Comment: at the very least you probably want `sum <- sum + (vals[i] * vals[i] )` ...

Comment: isn't i a reference to the value ?

Comment: oops, you're right.  Usually `i` is used as an index, confused me.

Answer (score 0):

```
g <- function( n , s , xb ) { 
vals <- rnorm( n - 1 , 0 , 1) 
sum<- sum(vals^2)
sigma <- sqrt ( s / sum )
z <- rnorm(1, 0 , 1)
mu <- ( z * ( sigma / sqrt(n) ) + xb )
print ( mu)
}
 g(10,6,3)
[1] 2.89561
```